# Chrome extension : Download/export content created "on the fly"

Tags: html, download, google-chrome-extension

I need to let the user to download a file created on the fly from some data contained in the extension, but I don't want to do this server-side.

As a real-world example : There is a variable containing the text "hello world". I want the user to be able to download/create a `.TXT` file containing such text.

Is it possible ?

-edited Oct 30, 2010-

Solutions so far:

**window.saveAs** - not working at all

**createObjectURL** - works, but the filename and other options can't be customized yet

**copy data to clipboard** - works, but too many steps are required to the user

**create a GoogleDocs document** - could work, but needs messing with the API and Oauth

-edited Apr 15, 2011

Looks like things are improving: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

But Chrome 14+ is still a bit weird about filenames.

Comment: Hey, did you find out how to do this?

Comment: I think the simplest and currently most modern way is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27928869/193017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to call save dialog through flash, see [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/) library.

Comment: Few hours ago I had no idea how to handle this, and now I have already two ways, thanks!

Comment: I've finally tested Downloadify, and it doesn't work due to the flash security sandbox. From the docs:

"**Important! The swf has been compiled for online use only. Testing from the file path (i.e. file:// ) will not work as it will violate the security sandbox.**"

I can't use the Blob option too, as it works only in the latest Chrome dev versions, so for now I can't provide any export function to the extension users... :(

Comment: The last copy of Downloadify is available at Web Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20101023200441/http://downloadify.info/ which in turn refers to https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Answer (score 2):

In the Chromium-extensions Google Group I have found this working example: (I have modified it to work from the pop-up)

```
BuiltBlob = new BlobBuilder(""); 
BuiltBlob.append("Hello, world"); 
BlobToSave = BuiltBlob.getBlob(); 
chrome.tabs.create({'url': createObjectURL(BlobToSave), 'selected': false});
```

But the filename is not set, ending with something like `cf8a56bf-d724-4b97-b10f-e252961135bd`

On the The W3C docs ( http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html ) I've found this **not working** example:

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder(); 
bb.append("Lorem ipsum"); 
var fileSaver = window.saveAs(bb.getBlob(), "test_file"); 
fileSaver.onwriteend = myOnWriteEnd;
```

but `window.saveAs` doesn't appear to exists.

Googleing around I've found outdated Google Gears references, but nothing else, maybe because I'm dealing with something too new to have proper documentation ?

Is there a way to set the filename/mime-type to the first example?

Comment: Well, HTML5 isn't even finished as a spec yet, let alone ready for full-scale implementation across the web. Unfortunately, HTML5 is 'the next big thing' just a bit too early. It's not surprising file writer doesn't work yet. You can always check HTML5test to see what your browser supports so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible because of safety reasons

Comment: This is a security red herring. There's no possible way it's less secure than downloading some arbitrary binary from a remote server (which is universally permitted)